# Having trouble understanding logic behind testing if numbers are prime or not

Tags: java

```
/**
 * The isPrime method iterates through every number in the range of 1 - 100 and adds every prime number to a 
   list in the file created by the user
 * @param filename The file that numbers will be added to
 */

public static void isPrime(String filename) throws IOException
{
   boolean status = true;          // tells method if number is prime or not (if status = true, number is prime)

   // opens up previously-created file for writing
   FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(filename, true);
   PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);

   for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
   {
       // check if each number is prime 
        status = checkPrime(i);

        if (status == true && i != 1)
        {
            outputFile.println(i);
        }
   }

   outputFile.close();
}

/**
 * The checkPrime method tests each number passed in as a parameter to see if it is prime
 * @param num Integer to be tested
 * @return Returns a boolean value of either true or false
 */

public static boolean checkPrime(int num)
{
    int remainder;              // used to test whether number is prime or not

    for (int j = 2; j < num; j++)
    {
        remainder = num % j;
        if (remainder == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So this is a segment from my assignment. The code runs, but what I need help with is understanding the logic of why the 2nd method, checkPrime() works.  I realize it's probably obvious, but I'm a new cs student, so if anyone is willing to explain why this works to me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: This is a really ambiguous question, since we don't know what you already know.  As it stands, you're basically asking us to teach you all the basics of Java in one answer.  You could greatly improve this question by narrowing down what it is you don't understand.  Include anything you've researched, and explain what **you** think each line does.  Then we have something to work with.  As it is, for all I know, I need to explain where each key is on the keyboard.

Comment: checkPrime() is a somewhat inefficient way of seeing if a number is prime. It loops from 2 to the number, and checks if the remainder after integer division (``remainder = num % j;``) is zero. If so, it returns false. Otherwise, if it goes through the entire loop, then it returns true, because the number is prime.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, there were 2 things throwing me off:  One, I was confused by how the 2nd loop was working, but I get it now.  The only thing I don't get now is how I could rework it to not include 1 as a prime number without just making it a condition to not include 1, if that makes any sense

Answer (score 1):

The % operator is the remainder operator. It is interating from 2 to `num` to see if the prime is divisible by any of those numbers.  As soon as it is, it can't be a prime so it returns false.  If finished and no divisor, it returns true.

But there is a more efficient way.  Only divide the candidate number `num` by values staring with `2` up to the square root of `num`.  Think about it, if there is no remainder up to that point, then no other number from the square root of `num`  to `num` will divide it.

So first check for divisibility by `2`.  Then starting with `3` by just the odd numbers.

So the method would look like this.

```
public static boolean checkPrime(int num)
{
    int remainder;              // used to test whether number is prime or not
    if(num % 2 == 0) {
         return false;
    }          
    for (int j = 3; j < (int)Math.sqrt(num)+1; j+=2)
    {
        remainder = num % j;
        if (remainder == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a prime number is a number that is only divisible by 1 or itself. For a number to be divisible the remainder of division should be 0.

**Examples**

5 is prime as it's only divisible by itself and 1:

- 5/5=1 remainder **0**
- 5/4=1 remainder 1
- 5/3=1 remainder 2
- 5/2=2 remainder 1
- 5/1=5 remainder **0**

While 4 is not prime because it's also divisible by 2:

- 4/4=1 remainder **0**
- 4/3=2 remainder 1
- 4/2=2 remainder **0**
- 4/1=4 remainder **0**

The operator `%` is used to calculate the remainder `5%2=1`.

Using this operator we can loop through all the numbers between `2` and `num`, `for (int j = 2; j < num; j++)` (we don't want to check `1` and `num` itself) and check the `remainder`, `if (remainder == 0)`. Once `remainder` is equal to `0`, the loop is broken and `false` is returned meaning the number is **not prime**. Otherwise, the loop finishes and the method returns `true` signalling that the number is **prime**.